# All the components of my angular project are not been uploaded on Github

Tags: angular, github

I am finding a peculiar problem while trying to upload my project in Github. While uploading my angular 4 project only the app component files are getting uploaded. The rest of the components are not getting uploaded in Github. However, Github is showing a vulnerability alert of

```
Known moderate severity security vulnerability detected in hoek < 4.2.1 defined in package-lock.json. package-lock.json update suggested: hoek ~> 4.2.1.
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. Is it because of the vulnerability alert my components are not uploading.

Here is my link of Github profile : 
https://github.com/uditgogoi/ExpenseManager/

**Solution :**

I did the following steps to sort this out:

1. npm uninstall hoek
2. npm update
3. npm install

Comment: According to https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/48783 you need to install npm i hoek in case you use vscode. If that is the case take a look at the issue.

Comment: Ya I followed the steps provided and it worked

Comment: Great. Glad that I helped.